# Java dialog loop bar

Tags: java, loops, progress-bar

I have a java program that uploads a tiny text file to a ftp server. Sometimes the upload can take up to 30 seconds because the server is very slow, which is a long time for the program to be idle. I want to know if there is a kind of "loop progress bar" (a progress bar kinda like when the windows is loading) to display while the user is waiting for the upload to finish.
A normal progress bar is out of the question. What I want is a "loop progress bar" if you can understand what i mean by it. Thank you
**Note:** What I want is kind like this image[image: loop progress bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html :

> Sets the indeterminate property of the progress bar, which determines
>   whether the progress bar is in determinate or indeterminate mode. An
>   indeterminate progress bar continuously displays animation indicating
>   that an operation of unknown length is occurring. By default, this
>   property is false. Some look and feels might not support indeterminate
>   progress bars; they will ignore this property.

Comment: thank you, I think this is it. The word that I was looking was indeterminate... :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a question that has been asked a lot. i have found when doing this to look for tutorials online.there is not a simple one line code you can add, but i have used this tutorial in the past, 
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-file-upload-progress-using-the-dojo-progressbar.html
i didnt want to try and reword what was already said here, the authors does a great job. if you have any questions after this i can answer more specific problems.

Comment: this is kinda like a progress bar, I can't express myself with the right words but what I want is a _loop progress bar_